# How well do ASP.NET and MySQL work together?

Tags: asp.net, mysql

What have your experiences been with asp.net and mysql?

Is it actually faster than mssql in terms of connection times etc?  Or is the library slower?

Is it suitable for a large scale type app?

Answer (score 0):

The answers to these questions are very subjective, and you may need to determine which is best for your needs.

The best approach, I believe, is to use unit testing to get a measure of how fast connections are, for example.

So, you have a test that is able to be used on both connection functions, and you can start to compare times.

How suitable will really depend on your needs, so, if you have the application requirements spelled out, then you can look and see which will best meet your needs.

MySQL is used in many large websites, and if you are using connection pooling then connection times don't matter, and for a very busy website a connection pool may be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a pretty bad experience with the  MySQL and ASP.Net combo. Connection pooling does *not* seem work, regardless of connection string settings or Connector version. The connections just stack up until the server is out of connection, even though I close all connections. For low-traffic websites, the lack of pooling might not matter that much but if you have a high-traffic site, it will affect performance.